# not able to use anaconda packages in django app

Tags: django, anaconda

I m new in python web development. I m using Django framework but i also need machine learning libraries so after installing django and working on it for a while i have installed anaconda distribution of python and i have directed my interpreter in pycharm to anaconda. The problem is when i import libraries like sklearn or pandas and then i run server, it gives me that error in command prompt

```
PS C:\Users\xxx\desktop\intelligent> python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03C62780>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\utils\a
utoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\core\ma
nagement\commands\runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\core\ma
nagement\base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\core\ma
nagement\base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\core\ch
ecks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\core\ch
ecks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\core\ch
ecks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\utils\f
unctional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\urls\re
solvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\utils\f
unctional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\urls\re
solvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\xxx\desktop\intelligent\intelligent\urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    url(r'^$', include('home.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\conf\ur
ls\__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\xxx\desktop\intelligent\home\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\xxx\desktop\intelligent\home\views.py", line 14, in <module>
    import pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

My setting.py file is unchanged. If i try to import libraries like sklearn without using django then it is running fine but in django app it gives above error even if the interpreter is set to anaconda in pycharm. I don't know if view.py file is useful or not but here it is

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import View
from .signupForm import UserForm
from .signinform import SignInForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

import pandas


# Create your views here.
@login_required(login_url='signin')
def index(request):
    context = {'app':'app'}
    return render(request,'home/index.html',context)

def signup(request):
    context = {'app':'app'}
    return render(request,'home/signup.html',context)

def signupform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index.html')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'home/signup.html', {'form': form})

def signinform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #form = SignInForm(request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        raw_password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index.html')

    else:
        form = SignInForm()
    return render(request, 'home/signin.html')

def logoutview(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('../signin')

def diagnosis(request):
   # result = main("8 1 3 100 150 1 2 77 1 1 2 2 3")
    context = {'app': 'app'}
    return render(request, 'home/diagnosis.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the logs the module **pandas** is missing.

```
  File "C:\Users\xxx\desktop\intelligent\home\views.py", line 14, in <module>
    import pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

You have to install it, with [pip](https://docs.python.org/2/installing/index.html) for example :

```
pip install pandas
```

Comment: what do i do if i want to use anaconda with django? Should i reinstall django with anaconda terminal ?